# Create target attributes ODI 12C

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I want to know if it's possible to create target attributes in ODI 12c directly in execution (temporary table maybe) without create each attribute in target table .

Because if we have a dimension with 200 attributes it wouldn't be funny to add each attribute singly .

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can!
just copy model from source database to target database in models in designer tab and on your map set create target table to **true** . But when your source and target database is different, You should consider **datatypes** in target model.

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't possible in an ODI 12c mapping unfortunately.
That can be done in a reusable mapping though, by using an output signature. However output signature are not physically persisted the database, it's more like a subquery.